# Growth of Fibonacci-Like Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

Let $S = \left( a_n \right)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a (non-trivial) sequence of real numbers such that $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 2$.

We (myself and a friend) are interested in the growth of the sequence $T = \left( |a_n| \right)_{n=0}^\infty$. **In particular, which initial values $a_0, a_1$ will result in the *slowest* growth of the terms of $T$?**

---

Through experimentation, we've come to the conjecture that for a given non-zero value of $a_0$, setting $a_1 = a_0 \psi$ yields the slowest growth of $T$ (where $\psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$).

Comment: What about $a_0 = a_1 = 0$?

Comment: Your conjecture is correct.  There is a standard method to find the general form of a solution of such a recurrence, in terms of the roots of an appropriate polynomial.

Comment: @Tunococ I forgot to mention that we are excluding that case.

Comment: @GEdgar Would you be able to point me towards somewhere that I can read about this?

Comment: It is called a homogeneous finite (or finite-order) difference equation. ("finite" as opposed to "infinitesimal", i.e. differential equation.)

Comment: Link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any T will satisfy $a_n = As^n +Bt^n$ for all $n$, for constants $A,B$, and $s,t$ are the solutions of $x^2=x+1$ (No co-incidence!), with $s=(1+\sqrt 5)/2$ and $t=(1-\sqrt 5)/2$................ Since $s>1$ and $-1<t<0$ it is clear that if $A\ne 0$ then $|a_n| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.......To keep this from happening we must have $A=0$, which of course gives $a_n=Bt^n$ for all $n$,  so $a_1=ta_0$.